# Spring Calling External API with two files - multipart/form-data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I have an external API that I am invoking. The API takes two files as input. One File is .txt and other file is .JOSN.

I need to call this API through spring. This api is multipart/form-data.

```
public String doAPICall(String uri, String token) {

File idFile = new File ("c:\tmp\id_file.txt");
File jsonFile = new File ("c:\tmp\jsonFile.json");

MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("idFile", new FileSystemResource(idFile));
body.add("jsonFile", new FileSystemResource(jsonFile));

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity= new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.exchange(
                uri, HttpMethod.POST,requestEntity,
                String.class).getBody().toString();

System.out.println(result);
return result;
```

}

Result: 500 - Internal Server Error. **However, If I invoke the API with the same config via Insomnia/Postman, it works.**
Also, it's not throwing 401 as the token is valid.

Do I need to set some extra header as I am uploading a txt and JSON file?

**PS: I have typed the code here, the code might not be well-formatted.**

Please share if anyone has any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Can you use `\\` instead of single `\` when you are doing `new File('\\your\\directory')`?

Comment: it was a double slash (\\\). Will edit my post.

Comment: can you also share the postman request which is working, both headers and body?

Comment: You can also try to generate the code in postman, and try to map out the differences.